# checking if two function return true not working

Tags: php

i have a form, once the user submits it, it goes to a handler page that calls two functions in another class that each checks part of the form inputs and sets sessions if values are wrong then return true if no session is set and false if one or more session is set, the handler should call both function and both of them should return true to continue with the code, the roblem is i check both of them in an if statement but only one of them is checked (whatever i put first)

```
 $driver = new LogRegValidation();

 if( $driver->userInfoValidate($password, $password2, $email, $phone, $db) ==true && $driver->carInfoValidate($plate, $db)==true)
{
//do something
}
```

if i put wrong values the sessions in userInfoValidate() are set alone, if i change the if statement and put carInfoValidate() first it are set alone.

```
 function userInfoValidate($password,$password2, $email, $phone,$db)
 {
     //checking values and setting sessions if wrong
    
    if( isset($_SESSION["f"])==false){
          
            return true; }
    
  }

function carInfoValidate($plate, $db)
{
           
          //checking values and setting sessions if wrong

           if(isset($_SESSION["z"])==false){
               
               return true; }
           
 }
```

Comment: Do your functions always return true when they succeed?  At the moment there isn't a return at the end of the function which will make the value *not true*

Comment: i set an else statement but am still facing the same problem